# Solr 3.1 Admin Interface

Tags: solr, admin

I am using Solr 1.4 , by default it comes with web application deployed as "solr.war" in webapps directory in example .
I tried to upgrade to solr 3.1 , but this vesrion (3.1) doesn't have attached web admin interface , 
I copied the solr.war from 1.4 and put it in webapps in 3.1
but this will lunch the 1.4 version of solr rather than 3.1  , I wanted to use edismax feature in 3.1 and other features and improvements , 
Please how can I use ediamx or give me regular steps to upgrade to solr 3.1 or even compile from source !!!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr 3.1 *does* have a web admin interface. The web application archive is in the `dist` directory of the official distribution, the file is named `apache-solr-3.1.0.war`

Comment: I didn't find the direcotry "dist" in apache solr 3.1 ?

Comment: @Muhannad: official distribution is here: http://www.apache.org/dist//lucene/solr/3.1.0/apache-solr-3.1.0.zip

Comment: Than you very much , but after all , I got the folloing message : when i tried to use dismax , Problem accessing /solr/dismax. Reason:

    can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: offer_click

Comment: @Muhannad: please create a new question with all details about this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

download the source package for 3.1
and run **"ant example"** to build the example solr application
the new war for 3.1 should be under solr/example/webapp dir.

you will need to add the following config in your solrconfig.xml
<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_31</luceneMatchVersion>

also make sure your **"unique id"** field in schema.xml is of type string

Comment: I tried to run ant example while i am in solr directory and while inside example directory , I got the following mesaage[ BUILD FAILED
Target "example" does not exist in the project "lucene-solr". 

Total time: 0 seconds'

Comment: there are two dirs in the downlaoded source package **solr** and **lucene**. You need to run **ant example** within the solr dir.